# jQuery - Not iterating correctly? (Too long to execute)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a snippet I've developed to increase the size of an image and take the td to the right of the image and drop it beneath.

However - it's taking a good few seconds, from the time it takes to remove the TD to add it in, and it makes the page rendering/paint/flow look terrible.

Please see the video below for a better understanding of what is happening.

http://screencast.com/t/RQdBiNyGkEm

Please also see my code snippet below;

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('html').addClass('js');
    $('.description').show();
    // add a td for initial page load of cart.
    $("table#shopping-cart-items tr td.image").after($('<td id="clearSpacePageLoad"></td>'));
    // take content from right - and drop it beneath the image

    $('#shopping-cart-items > tbody > tr').each(function() {
      var desc = $('td.description', this).html()
      $('td.description', this).remove();
      $('td.image', this).append(desc);
    });
  }); 
  </script>
  
  <script>

  //When selecting a delivery method - everything resets due to AJAX.

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Use .live() in stead of .on() since jQuery is < 1.9
  // On select of delivery method do the following
  $('.shippingOpt').live('click', function() {
    // Wait for ALL ajax requests on page (Past and future) to execute BEFORE executing the following
    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
      // Repeat the same code as initial page load.
      $('img.item-img').each(function() {
        var str = $(this).attr('src'),
          arr = str.split("?");
        query = "?hei=200&wid=200&op_sharpen=1"
        $(this).attr('src', arr[0] + query);
      });

      $('#shopping-cart-items > tbody > tr').each(function() {
        var desc = $('td.description', this).html()
        $('td.image', this).append(desc);
        $('td.description', this).remove();
      });


      // If ID of 'clearSpaceOnClick' exists don't add another td, if it doesn't - add it!
      if ($('#clearSpaceOnClick').length) {} else {
        $("table#shopping-cart-items tr td.image").after($('<td id="clearSpaceOnClick"></td>'));
      }
    });
  });
}); 
</script>
```

```html
<style>
  .checkoutBasket table.cart-container td.image img {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
  }
  #clearSpace {
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: the code snippet is an  empty page.

Comment: I'm not seeing any image getting bigger in your screencast. A fiddle or live example would be more useful

Comment: @MinaJacob I'm injecting this onto the webpage as I dont have direct access to the source code.

Comment: @yezzz - the CSS is making it bigger so it's shown larger before page load - in the screencase I'm simply refreshing.

I can't give a live example as it's a staging environment - and the source code needs to be compiled in order to be seen.
straight HTML wont work here.

I'm just wondering if anything jumps out at the way I've ordered my jquery that would make this delay happen.

Comment: so, what can be seen after around 5-6 sec is the original look, and around 8 sec it shows the script result?

Comment: the load snip is faster because it remove()s before it append()s, so the table is never in need of a full-height reflow.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the video, you are almost certainly injecting an additional `td`  element and now there are more `td`s on the row than there are columns in your table. You should be able to see an issue if you inspect element.

Off hand, I would look very closely at the logic related to the line below but you dont give us your html so we cant know for sure:

`$("table#shopping-cart-items tr td.image").after($('<td id="clearSpaceOnClick"></td>'));`

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple `td.image` in `table#shopping-cart-items` then you should not append an element with an ID (as ID's must be unique), which you're doing in 2 places in your code.

It looks like you might be selecting an (already active) shipping option. In that case ajaxstop may be delaying things if there are any outstanding ajax requests.

Also, jQuery .on has been available since v1.7, not 1.9